# Loops in R - linear regression

Tags: r, loops, regression, linear-regression, zoo

I've just started out learning R and can't seem to get this loop to work. I have a data frame containing 250 rows and 503 columns (y) and another data frame containing 250 rows and 1 column (x).

I am trying to get a loop to run 503 separate regressions without having to type it in individually ie.

```
(output_1 <- lm(y$1st column ~ x))
(output_2 <- lm(y$2nd column ~ x))
```

across all 250 rows in each regression.

I tried this loop:

```
for (i in 1:503) {
output_loop <- lm(y[,i]~x)
}
output_total <- cbind(output$coefficients)
```

but this only gave me one intercept and one coefficient, as opposed to 503 intercepts and 503 coefficients.

The rows of each data frame have time markers that are aligned in the format yyyy-mm-dd but I don't believe this affects the regression as the intercept and coefficients output sought are independent of time.

I have also tried using a basic lm:

```
(output <- lm(y~x))
 output_total <- cbind(output$coefficients)
```

and this gives 503 intercepts and 503 coefficients, however the output is wrong when I spot checked the output against some columns (running individual regression as above).

Any help on this loop is much appreciated!

Thank you

Comment: lm(y~x) where x is more than one column is multiple regression, the coefficients will not match the coefficients from each of the 503 separate regressions.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you're approaching this the best way, but here's something that I think will achieve what you described.

```
# create some toy data to match your description

set.seed(340)
y <- data.frame(replicate(503, runif(250, 0, 1)))
x <- data.frame(v1=runif(250, 0, 1))


out <- data.frame(NULL)              # create object to keep results
for (i in 1:length(y)) {
  m <- summary(lm(y[,i] ~ x[,1]))    # run model
  out[i, 1] <- names(y)[i]           # print variable name
  out[i, 2] <- m$coefficients[1,1]   # intercept
  out[i, 3] <- m$coefficients[2,1]   # coefficient
}
names(out) <- c("y.variable", "intercept", "coef.x")
head(out)

# y.variable intercept       coef.x
# 1         X1 0.4841710 -0.015186852
# 2         X2 0.4972775 -0.002306964
# 3         X3 0.4410326  0.096450185
# 4         X4 0.4547249  0.041582039
# 5         X5 0.5039661  0.062429142
# 6         X6 0.5331573 -0.092806309
```

Comment: your example is not reproducible (try using `y <- data.frame(replicate(5, runif(250, 0, 1)))` instead). But as Aaron comments, you can do this in one step without a loop.  `coef(lm(as.matrix(y) ~ as.matrix(x)))`

Comment: i get that a loop is not required (are they ever?), but sometimes loops make it easier to understand what is happening. maybe not in this case. but i don't follow why the example is not reproducible. if i restart R and run again i get the same results. am i missing something?

Comment: re your example, the first line uses sapply over y, before y is defined (perhaps you have a y getting loaded in your workspace when you restart??)

Comment: yep, got it. thanks. `y` was left over in my environment.

Comment: I tried this but got this on the console "Error in `*tmp*`[[j]] : subscript out of bounds". Also, 

 `coef(lm(as.matrix(y) ~ as.matrix(x))) ' would give the wrong intercepts and coefficients, similar to:
' (output <- lm(y~x))
 output_total <- cbind(output$coefficients) '

Comment: @ejt not sure what would cause that. maybe try clearing your workspace and running the example again. confirmed that it works.

Answer (score 0):

Your loop is close you just need to create a place to catch the results.

```
output_loop=list(NA)
for (i in 1:503) {
output_loop[[i]] <- lm(y[,i]~x)

}
```

If you just want the coefficients in a data.frame then restructure things to catch just the two coefficients from each model

```
output_loop=data.frame(int=NA,slope=NA)
for (i in 1:503) {
  output_loop[i,] <- coefficients(lm(y[,i]~x))

}
```

Comment: This works! Thank you. If I type in "output_loop" in the console it gives me all 503 intercepts and coefficients such as 

    ' [[503]]

    Call:
    lm(formula = y[, i] ~ x)

    Coefficients:
    (Intercept)            x ' 

However I would lose the header of all 503 columns. Is there a way to preserve the header of the columns and have two rows for the intercept and coefficient? I'm trying variations of:

    ' output_total <- as.matrix(output_loop) '

with no luck.

Thanks again

Comment: There are a couple good strategies. If all you want is just the intercept and slope then just organize the output from a list to a data frame. If you want more stuff from the regression outputs then the list that I set up gets that for you. I added the data frame structured result so you have both.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a "tidy" solution based on the tidyverse and broom packages:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(broom)


set.seed(340)
y <- data.frame(replicate(503, runif(250, 0, 1)))
x <- data.frame(v1=runif(250, 0, 1))

y %>%
    pivot_longer(everything(), names_to = "variable", values_to = "y") %>%
    split(.$variable) %>%
    map(., ~ mutate(., x = x$v1)) %>% # Note that v1 is the name of MY data frame x
    map(., ~ lm(y ~ x, data = .)) %>%
    map(tidy) %>% # This bit here extracts the model parameters. If you want any other information, you could use summary()
    imap_dfr(., ~ mutate(.x, variable = .y))

#> # A tibble: 1,006 x 6
#>    term         estimate std.error statistic  p.value variable
#>    <chr>           <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl> <chr>   
#>  1 (Intercept)  0.484       0.0361  13.4     3.72e-31 X1      
#>  2 x           -0.0152      0.0631  -0.241   8.10e- 1 X1      
#>  3 (Intercept)  0.499       0.0356  14.0     2.84e-33 X10     
#>  4 x           -0.00601     0.0622  -0.0967  9.23e- 1 X10     
#>  5 (Intercept)  0.492       0.0344  14.3     3.03e-34 X100    
#>  6 x            0.000321    0.0600   0.00534 9.96e- 1 X100    
#>  7 (Intercept)  0.530       0.0361  14.7     1.65e-35 X101    
#>  8 x           -0.0972      0.0631  -1.54    1.25e- 1 X101    
#>  9 (Intercept)  0.534       0.0357  15.0     1.77e-36 X102    
#> 10 x           -0.0144      0.0623  -0.231   8.18e- 1 X102    
#> # ... with 996 more rows
```

<sup>Created on 2019-12-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>